# How to invoke App Insights Shared Query (from another workspace)

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics, kql

I have a Shared Query in an App Insights workspace, and I would like to invoke it and use its results in Log Analytics workspace. Is this possible, and if so, what is the syntax?

I am able to access the App Insights tables from Log Analytics by doing `app("app insights name").tableName` so I know the cross-workspace situation should allow this if invoking a shared query is at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to find documents on cross-resource query with the shared query but failed.

And in my opinion, it's also impossible to achieve it. Shared query is used to save a usual kql and share it with other users which has permission to access that application insights instance. I tried to sign in another account and I can see the shared query in the menu. It's designed for share not play the role as a function to call in some other place.

Per my testing, with cross-resource we can also get the same result as what in app insights.

[image]

I think you can save the cross-resource query as a function in log analytics workspace so that you can use it directly without writing it each time you wanna use this query. Just click the save button and select save as function.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the detailed information-- to summarize, you can't "invoke" a shared query, only select it which makes the full query text appear in the editor. If the shared query was instead saved as a function in the log analytics, then I can simply call it. Is that about right?

Comment: yes exactly, what you said is what I got from my testing : )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try saving your query to a Query Pack.

Query packs are query 'containers' that are accessible in all Log Analytics instances. So you can save your query without specifying the workspace—and use it everywhere.

[Read more about Query Packs](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-monitor/log-analytics-query-packs/ba-p/2314721).